# Do comment flags contribute to the deputy badge on Politics?

Tags: discussion, badges

Firstly, [I know a question exists on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123335/do-comment-flags-deemed-helpful-apply-to-badge-requirements) for this very thing, but I have 83 helpful flags and haven't received the Deputy badge (over three hours ago). So I'm here to learn a little.

[image: flagging history]   [image]

I'm not quite sure what the semantics of Beta websites are,

- Does the acknowledgement refresh over a certain period of time? or
- Do I need more *normal* flags moreover comment flags to receive
  it?

I'm not overly bothered about the badge itself (as I like to contribute to this website in any way I can), but I just want to learn more about the process of beta sites moreover say The Workplace (the [answer in the aforementioned question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150079/350945) for example) as those whom answered also couldn't find any documentation. So it begs the question, is it different for Beta?

Comment: I'd wait a couple of days for it.  Usually these kinds of badges get applied by a routine maintenance job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the Badge as @SamIam rightly pointed out in the comments. So, yes helpful comment flags on Beta sites contribute to the Deputy badge in the same way they do on fully fledged ones, but over a longer period of time i.e. a routine maintenance job.